# Fake proof for a sequence convergence to a limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fake-proofs

Where does a false proof of a sequence breaks down. For example the sequence:
$$\lim_{} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=1$$
If I want to prove that a sequence converges to a limit other than 1, take $0$.

Is it the absolute value that is incorrect, in that case why?
$$\left\vert \frac{n+1}{n} -0 \right \vert 
=\left\vert \frac{n+1}{n}  \right \vert = \frac{n+1}{n} $$
$$ \frac{n+1}{n}<\epsilon \Rightarrow n+1<\epsilon n \Rightarrow1 <\epsilon n-n \Rightarrow 1 <n( \epsilon-1) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon-1}<n  $$
This is a question from the book understanding analysis by Stephen Abbott that a really can't get my head around.

Comment: the equality is right, give us the proof so we can find the problem

Comment: the limit as $n$ approaches ...?

Comment: we can omit this because it's a sequence

Comment: By definition $lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)=L $ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists natural number $N$ so that $n>N\implies |f(n)-L|<\epsilon$. So you can dispute the claim of a limit relationship if you negate that, i.e., there exists $\epsilon >0$ so that $|f(n)-L|>\epsilon$ no matter how big N is.

Comment: I change it a bit, hopefully it would be a bit easier to understand

Comment: The big string of implications (third line from the bottom) is not valid for all values of $\epsilon$.   Insert $\epsilon=\frac12$ and it fails.   In any case there is no proof here, only the preliminary scribbles that one makes before writing up a formal proof.

Comment: @B. S. Thompson: on the contrary, the string of implications seems absolutely correct – it’s just that the premise is wrong and so it’s vacuous…

Comment: the problem is that for $\varepsilon < 1$ we cannot just divide by $1 - \varepsilon$ without changing the direction of the inequality sign

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is wrong because It does not work for $\epsilon$ less than 1. Since $\epsilon$ is required to be taken as small as possible, you could assume without to lose the generality that all $\epsilon$ in all proofs are less than one. This assumption would make Impossible to make the passage $$ 1< n (\epsilon -1 ) \implies \dfrac{1}{\epsilon -1 } < n. $$ The actual passage is  $$ 1< n (\epsilon -1 ) \implies \dfrac{1}{\epsilon -1 } > n$$ because the quantity $(\epsilon -1 )$ is negative which requires changing the sign of less than to bigger than.  The actual needed last conclusion is impossible.

Comment: I see the problem, thanks

Comment: I’m afraid this makes the same logical mistake (or is it an omission?) as the OP: what serves to prove the convergence is the *converse* statement (which is blatantly wrong, of course, for the reasons you explained) – but the forward statement (given $\epsilon >0$ such that $\frac{n+1}{n} <\epsilon$, $\frac{1}{\epsilon-1} < n$) given by the string of implications is completely correct. It’s just useless in this case.

Comment: @Mindlack.  Not sure of your point.  The implication $ 1 <n( \epsilon-1) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon-1}<n$  is valid only for $\epsilon >1$ and is false for $\epsilon \leq 1$.   It is particularly egregious for $\epsilon=1$.  I agree that the argument here has no use for anything.

Comment: @B. S. Thompson: I beg to differ. If $\epsilon \in (0,1]$, then $1< n(\epsilon-1)$ is a false claim and therefore it implies anything.

Comment: @Mindlack  I see your point.  But Prado's answer is excellent, in spite of your quibble.

Comment: All the confusion appears because a false statement is tried to be proven. Pointing out where the error appears in such situations is the best we could do, and the correct way of arguing the proof is wrong.  I don't want to be a judge of values and say the ultimate reason why the proof is wrong, but just point out where the error appears.

Comment: @B. S. Thomson: perhaps it is – you certainly seem better qualified than I am to assess it. But in my opinion, this answer misses the underlying issue – the logic. I don’t think the problem is the sign quibble – it’s that nothing on this kind of basis can possibly come close to a “false proof” because the reasoning assumes the conclusion and draws a series of formal implications hoping to get… whatever it’s trying to get.